# Moment.js doesn't humanize simple hours

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I am using moment.js in a website in which I have to show duration between different periods. I get the milisecond duration, and after dividing by 3600 * 1000 I get a decimal hours format. I am trying to use the humanize method from `moment.js` but there is not exact enough.

This are example behaviours of the library

```
moment.duration(0.5, 'hours').humanize();   // returns '30 minutes' OK
moment.duration(0.1, 'hours').humanize();   // returns '6 minutes' OK
moment.duration(0.8, 'hours').humanize();   // returns 'an hour' BAD
moment.duration(0.7, 'hours').humanize();   // returns '42 minutes' OK
moment.duration(0.72, 'hours').humanize();  // returns '43 minutes' OK
moment.duration(0.73, 'hours').humanize();  // returns '44 minutes' OK
moment.duration(0.74, 'hours').humanize();  // returns '44 minutes' OK
moment.duration(0.75, 'hours').humanize();  // returns 'an hour' BAD
```

What is happening and how is the moment.js-way to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default [Relative Time Threshold](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) for minutes is 45 minutes.

> `duration.humanize` has thresholds which define when a unit is considered a minute, an hour and so on. For example, by default more than 45 seconds is considered a minute, more than 22 hours is considered a day and so on. To change those cutoffs use `moment.relativeTimeThreshold(unit, limit)` where unit is one of `ss`, `s`, `m`, `h`, `d`, `M`.

If you would like a higher cutoff point, set a different value by doing:

```
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 60);
```

```js
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 60);

console.log([
  moment.duration(0.5, 'hours').humanize(),
  moment.duration(0.1, 'hours').humanize(),
  moment.duration(0.8, 'hours').humanize(),
  moment.duration(0.7, 'hours').humanize(),
  moment.duration(0.72, 'hours').humanize(),
  moment.duration(0.73, 'hours').humanize(),
  moment.duration(0.74, 'hours').humanize(),
  moment.duration(0.75, 'hours').humanize()
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2j10p8p2/)